# Assigning a int to a double&

Tags: c++, reference

I would like to understand why this doesn't compile:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    double& b = a;
    std::cout << b;
}
```

While using `double const& b = a` instead of `double& b = a` works fine.

Comment: What do you intend the program to do?

Comment: Because the types don't match. C++ is trying to prevent you from making a big mistake.

Comment: How can a `double&` reference an `int` variable?!? Are you sure you understood what a reference is?

Comment: Even if `int` and `double` are the same size so you don't wander out side, say, a 32 bit `int` when reading it as a `double`, the byte encoding of an `int` will make no sense interpreted as a `double`.

Comment: 1) my program was longer, but there was no point showing it, the problem is these lines
2)if i use double const& =a; it works, so i don't understand why it work using const and doesn't without.
3)I thought it would convert automatically the type of a from int to double

Comment: "thought it would convert automatically the type of a from int to double" - no, I dont know any programming language where that is the case.

Comment: int main() 
    {
    int a = 1;
    double b = a;
    std::cout << b;
    }

Here converts the a to double then assing the value of a to b. This is an automatic convertion, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `double` and an `int` have different alignment requirements and different representation in memory. Reading a variable as one type through the eyes of another type would also make your program have undefined behavior.

When you do something like

```
int a = 1;
double b = a;  // note, not a reference
```

then `a` is implicitly converted to a temporary `double` that is then assigned to `b`. If you instead do

```
double& b = a;
```

then `b` tries to reference that temporary `double`, which is invalid since the temporary will be destroyed at the end of the expression.

You *can* however prolong the life of the temporary beyond the end of the expression by using a `const&`. The life of the temporary will then be extended to the end of the reference's life (the end of the scope).

Example:

```
const double& b = a; // valid, but usually pointless
```

---

Regarding your addition to the question:

> While using `double const& b = a` instead of `double& b = a` works fine

That is just because "the standard says so". A non-`const&` to a temporary implies that you want to make changes to that temporary - which is often a mistake and you probably would want a `double` instead of a `double&` in those cases.

Comment: Thanks I'm really new to programming so also the easiest thing are not so obvious for me

Comment: @DavideLP You're welcome and I can totally see why this isn't obvious. I just noticed that you made an addition regarding `const&` so I added a note about that to the end.

Comment: To extend the subtle difference, `int a = 5; int const& b = a; a = 6;` now b is also 6.  `int a = 5; double const& b = a; a = 6;` but b is still 5.0 since it is an alias to the unnamed temporary.

Comment: @Eljay Yes, good illustration!